# Concatenating a pointer to a string literal in a Macro

Tags: c, string

I need to append the function name of the caller concatenated wit brackets at the beginning of the string so it looks like `[<FUNCTION_NAME>] <string>` but rather I am getting `[name] <string>` as an output...possibly it has to do with `#` stringifying the variable passed in but how do you get it to work?

```c
#define FUN(STR)                           "["#STR"] "

void foo(const char *name, char *fmt, ...)
{
    char buff[100] = {0};
    va_list pList;
    
    va_start(pList, fmt);
    int ret = vsprintf(buff, fmt, pList);
    va_end(pList);
    
    char p[100] = {0};
    sprintf (p, "%s%s", FUN(name), buff);
    printf ("%s\n", p);   // [name] Some string with value = 5
}

void bar()
{
    foo(__func__, "Some string with value = %d", 5);
}

int main() 
{
    bar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sooooo `printf("[%s]%s", name, buff)`?

Comment: certainly not...

Comment: why certainly not?

Comment: I just don't to print it; I wanna have a pointer point to it since it's used elsewhere in a program

Comment: sooo `sprintf(p, "[%s]%s", name, buff)` the same.

Comment: my goodness...was it this easy?

Comment: why would a macro approach not work?

Comment: Macro works on _text_, not on variables, variables do not exists for preprocessor. `#` applies `#` operation on _text_ `name`, so it becomes `"name"`.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the brackets in printf format string.

```
printf("[%s]%s", name, buff)
```

But it sounds like a waste to have two buffers. Just have one buffer. Also, the code needs protection against overload. Needed checks need to be added to protect against overflowing the buffer. Also, prefer to use `snprintf` over `sprintf`.

```
#define MIN(a, b)  ((a)<(b)?(a):(b))

#ifdef __GNUC__
#if __GNUC__ > 10
__attribute__((__access__(read_only, 1)))
#endif
__attribute__((__format__(__printf__, 2, 3)))
#endif
void foo(const char *name, char *fmt, ...)
{
    char buff[10];
    char *p = buff;
    const char *const end = buff + sizeof(buff);
    // Add bracket.
    static_assert(sizeof(buff) > 0, "");
    *p++ = '[';
    // Add name.
    const size_t namelen = strlen(name);
    size_t free = end - p;
    // Leave space for 0 either way.
    const size_t tocopy = MIN(free - 1, namelen);
    memcpy(p, name, tocopy);
    p += tocopy;
    // Add "] ". Wonder, maybe it should be <=, not sure.
    if (p < end - 1) {
        *p++ = ']';
    }
    if (p < end - 1) {
        *p++ = ' ';
    }
    // Add printf stuff
    free = end - p;
    if (free > 1) {
        // It's odd that there is no vfoo(..., va_list va); overload.
        va_list va;
        va_start(va, fmt);
        const int r = vsnprintf(p, free + 1, fmt, va);
        va_end(va);
        (void)r;
        assert(r >= 0); // unneeded, pedantic: check errors
    } else {
        // Och, we remember about it.
        assert(p < end);
        *p = 0;
    }

    printf("%s\n", buff);
}
```

> why would a macro approach not work?

In short: Macros work on *text*. Variables do not exist for preprocessor, only other macros. `#` applies `#` operation on *text* `name`, so it becomes `"name"`, in effect the call becomes;

```
sprintf (p, "%s%s", "[" "name" "] ", buff);
```

Adjacent `"this" "that"` string literals are concatenated together into one `"thisthat"`, and `%s` just prints it all.

Comment: " it sounds like a waste to have two buffers. ". I am passing in two different params and combining them into a function hence two "buffers". Once the string is concat'd, one buffer is used. By overflowing the buffer, you meant to make sure a max of 99 bytes are written? Also mind elaborating on protecting against the overload? not sure if I got a point

Comment: `I am passing in two different params and combining them into a function hence two "buffers". Once the string is concat'd, one buffer is used` Use one buffer from the start. `you meant to make sure a max of 99 bytes are written? ` yes. `Also mind elaborating on protecting` I do not understand.. The logic is: `if (characters_written >= sizeof(buff)) { do_not_write_more_characters_to_buff(); { else { continue_writing_more_characters_to_buff(); }`